# Make div height grow and shrink when scrolling (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Basically I've got a div at the top of my website which has the logo, initially the logo has a height and the div is going to size to the logo height (200px in the pen).

What I want to do is, make the logo smaller while I scroll down, or bigger while I scroll up, basically the scrollY value needs to be somehow linked to the image heigh (until I get to a point scroling down where I don't want to keep shrinking the logo).

I've tried setting the height css property with a state and updating it with an eventlistener that updates the state every time it detects scrolling.

This didn't worked (but maybe I coded that wrong).

Any ideas how could I do this?

Here's the JS:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="container">

                            <img src='https://www.import.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/React-logo-1.png' className='logo'/>

                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.body);
```

Here's the CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: $color6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.logo {
    height: 200px;
}
```

And here's the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqdjNO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set an event on scroll and update style. See the pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEoPxY?editors=0110

CSS :

```
@import "compass/css3";

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
}

.empty-space {
    height: 800px;
}

.container {
    background-color: $color6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    /*height: 200px;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript :

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            style: {
                logoHeight: 200
            }
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },

    handleScroll: function(event) {
        let scrollTop = window.scrollY,
                minHeight = 30,
                logoHeight = Math.max(minHeight, 200 - scrollTop);
        this.setState({
            style: {
                logoHeight: logoHeight
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container" style={{height: this.state.style.logoHeight}}>
                    <img src='https://www.import.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/React-logo-1.png' className='logo'/>
                </div>
                <div className="empty-space">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.body);
```

Comment: It's pretty much what I tried myself but I had no getInitialState, anyways that worked, so thanks a lot man!!